# Django auto increment model

Tags: python, django

I design Django Model as shown below :

`

```
class User(models.Model):
      id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      username=models.CharField(max_length=25,verbose_name="username")
      name=models.CharField(max_length=20,default="noName",verbose_name="name")
      password=models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name="password")
      email=models.EmailField()
      userCode=models.CharField(default=" ",max_length=100,verbose_name="User Code")

      def __str__(self):
            return self.username

      class Meta:
            ordering = ['-username']`
```

Then I create an object in view.py. Although id is auto incremented, python want me to define an id. View.py is shown below.

```
def register(request,id):
if request.method=='POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        name=form.cleaned_data["name"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
        email=form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        newUser = User(1,username,name,password,email)
        newUser.save()
        return redirect('mainPage')
     else:
        form=RegisterForm()
context = {
        "form" : form,
        "id":id
}
return render(request,"SignupLogin.html",context)
```

User(1,username,name,password,email) in that line, 1 is the id number. When I delete it, error which is about missing variable id, is thrown. How can I get rid of 1?

Comment: In this line `id-models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`, there should be `=` b/w column name and column type, not `-`. Is this a typo while adding your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just introduce your parameters to `model` init function. That might help :)

```
newUser = User(username=username, name=name, password=password, email=email)
```

and if you have `nullable` fields `(null=True)` you must describe it on model.

Comment: Creating object like you wrote, solve the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare an autoincrementing primary key field by hand – Django implicitly adds an `id` field for you if there is none.

Your problem is likely not having set `editable=False` on that manually created field of yours.